# block user object settings at cross domain forest registration

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, citrix

I got the following infrastrucute: 
Domain A: User Forest |
Domain B: Ressource Forest (Citrix AD with infrastructure services) |
one way trust-relationship

The user of domain A signs on the citrix server at domain B. 
The problem is: The user object has a home folder, which tries to connect to the XenApp Server at domain B. But those servers are not reachable using routing. That is why the sign on process lasts up to 60 seconds. 
Windows tries to connect the drive and does not stop until a certain timeout is reached.

The question is: Is there any possibility to avoid the connection to the home drive or is it possible to prevent the application of the ad-user-object-preferences?

I highly appreciate any answers.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to [Manage User Profiles for Remote Desktop Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742820.aspx).

Create GPO which set the following parameter:

```
Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Profiles
```

Policy: "Set Remote Desktop Services User Home Directory"
Setting: Enabled

Location: On the local machine
HomeDir root path: [drive letter]:\[some directory that users have permission to create folders and CreatorOwner has full control]